# Extract selected rows from a Listbox in Access

Tags: ms-access, listbox, multi-select, ms-access-2016

In Access, I'm trying to extract the selected items from a List Box.

I haven't used the List Box object for a while, but I seem to remember that you have to loop through the selected items and then extract them using the `List` method.

My research supports this ascertation, but I'm running in to problems in relation to the use of `List` -

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

Printing the `lstLocations.Selected(i)` sees `-1` returned for every selection, and `List` apparently doesn't exist, so how can extract the selected values?

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To lstLocations.ListCount - 1
    If lstLocations.Selected(i) Then
        Debug.Print lstLocations.List(i)
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the for each loop to loop through the selected items. 
something like

```
        Dim item As Variant
        For Each item In Me.lbx_booking.ItemsSelected
            If Not (Nz(Me.lbx_booking.Column(0, item), "") = "") Then

            End If
        Next item
```